# Displacement map render shows visible lines

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

I have prepared a displacement map using dem images. While rendering, a line border is coming around the border of the map. How do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image lookup is set to clip, so any values outside the 0,1 UV range will return 0,0,0 black.  But if we sample the colors of the borders of the image, we find that the color at the border is not actually 0 black-- it is about 1/255 gray.  This creates a discontinuity at the edges of the UV range which is apparent on your image.

We can fix this just by clamping the texture lookup to a particular high enough range that it will flatten everything-- we'll raise everything below a certain value, up to that value:

[image]

I'm doing that with a math/maximum node, which will raise everything below 0.01 to 0.01, erasing that boundary.

I tuned down my rendering settings pretty significantly from what you had in order to troubleshoot, in case you're wondering about the render.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me!